# React Hooks - Remove Specific Item from an array using Index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two arrays,

```
const [imagesUrlArray, setURls] = useState([])

  const [imagesArray, setImages] = useState([])
```

using handle change below; imagesUrlArray is used to display the images on the screen, and imagesArray is saved to later update those same images to the database

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    let selected = e.target.files[0]
        var selectedImageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(selected);
        addUrl(selectedImageSrc)
        addImage(selected)
    };
```

Though I now want to click the X(delete) button and remove the item at index of imagesUrlArray and imagesArray (say if the user no longer wants to use that image)

```
<div className="img-grid">
{ imagesUrlArray && imagesUrlArray.map((url,index) => {

  return ( <div  key={index}
    className="img-wrap">
       {/* <span class="close">&times;</span> */}
       <button onClick={ () => handleRemove(index)} className="close">X</button>
       
<img src={url} alt="uploaded" />
        </div>
)
   }
)}
</div>
```

I have tried splice and slice etc but still cannot find a perfect solution,

here is the handleRemove Function

```
const handleRemove = (index) => {

  
  const newImagesArray = imagesArray.splice(index);

  const newImagesUrlArray = imagesUrlArray.splice(index);

  setImages(newImagesArray);

  setURls(newImagesUrlArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const handleRemove = (index) => {

  setImages(imagesArray.filter((x,i) => i !== index));

  setURls(imagesUrlArray.filter((x,i) => i !== index));

}
```

So, basically the idea is to skip the element at specific index and return the remaining items and set the state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works a charm, have a great day or night.